# How to pass json data from controller to view in EXTJS 4.0

Tags: extjs

I have a combobox declared inside my grid

```
header: '<b>Reasons</b>',
            width : 150,
            editor:
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    store: 'reasonstore',
                    displayField: 'displayText',
                    valueField: 'value',
                    queryMode: 'local',

                }
```

and my store is

var reasonstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['displayText', 'value'],
                id : 'resonstoreid'
            });

I have done a rest call and got my jsondata in controller

```
successCallback:function(json){
            var mydata = json.reason;
Ext.getCmp('resonstoreid').getStore().loadData(json.reason);
```

but i m getting Ext.getCmp('resonstoreid') is undefined.
my view is only loading first then the controller.
so how to load this json data from controller to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[Ext.getStore("xxx")](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-getStore)** to get a reference to your store! This should solve your problem.

```
var store = Ext.getStore("resonstoreid");
store.loadData(json.reason);
```

**An other advice**

Instead of making a AJAX call, and fill the store with `loadData(xxx)` use `load()` function of the store. See here: [Ext.data.Store.load](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load)

Do to that, your store config should look like this

```
//create File store/Reasons.js 
Ext.define('XYZ.store.Reasons', {  //XYZ ... you namespace
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    fields: ['displayText', 'value'], 
    id : 'Reasons',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        actionMethods:  {create: 'POST', read: 'GET', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'},
        url: 'xxx',
        method: 'POST',            

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

After that, you can do this:

```
var store = Ext.getStore("Reasons");
store.load(
    params: {
        group: 3,
        type: 'user'
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // do something after the load finishes
    },
    scope: this
});
```

The advantage would be a better app structure and that `load` does the ajax request for you. This is exactly what extjs is great for: Split up the code in many small files which are easy to maintain (code reuse, etc...).

Comment: Thnks a lott...it worked..bt now when i select a value from combo box, after selecting the value field is getting displayed instead of display field...any suggestion for this plzz...

Comment: That usually indicates the combo store is not loaded or the record with that value is not found.

Comment: Look if if the data is loaded correctly. In the console try this store = Ext.getStore("resonstoreid"); store.data.items[0].data; What is the output?